# Swift: Why doesn't JSONDecoder (Codable/Decodable) call the init() method of the struct?

Tags: swift

I feel there's something I must be missing. Swift 5.1.

I have the following `struct` which is set to be `Decodable` so I can parse an external JSON URL:

```
struct ReleaseGroup: Decodable, Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let externalServiceID: String
  let title: String
  let externalServiceImageURL: URL
  let type: String
  var image: UIImage?

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case externalServiceID = "external_service_id"
    case title
    case externalServiceImageURL = "external_service_image_url"
    case type
  }

  // do I have to do this just because UIImage is an optional?
  init(id: Int, externalServiceID: String, title: String, externalServiceImageURL: URL, type: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://someurl.com/some-image.jpeg")
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.id = id
    self.externalServiceID = externalServiceID
    self.title = title
    self.type = type
    self.externalServiceImageURL = externalServiceImageURL
  }
}
```

I've also defined this piece of code elsewhere, which is responsible for actually creating the instances from the API call:

```
init() {
  guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/releases/") else { return }
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in

    guard let data = data else { return }

    let releaseGroups = try! JSONDecoder().decode([ReleaseGroup].self, from: data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.releaseGroups = releaseGroups
      }
    }
    }.resume()
}
```

However, the above doesn't call the `init()` method of `ReleaseGroup`, which I thought is called any time an instance of `ReleaseGroup` is created.

If I explicitly create them though, it works:

```
for releaseGroup in releaseGroups {
          let rg = ReleaseGroup.init(id: releaseGroup.id, externalServiceID: releaseGroup.externalServiceID, title: releaseGroup.title, externalServiceImageURL: releaseGroup.externalServiceImageURL, type: releaseGroup.type)
            self.releaseGroups.append(rg)
        }
```

Comment: It will call `init(from:)` which is part of the `Decodable` protocol. This init is synthesized so if you need to do something special with your object construction this is the init method you need to implement.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - so I need to override `init(from:)` in the struct `ReleaseGroup`?

Comment: Yes, see  [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - this worked, can you add as an answer so I can vote and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decoder will call `init(from:)` which is part of the `Decodable` protocol. This init is synthesized so if you need to do something special with your object construction this is the init method you need to implement yourself.

See [this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for more information